# How to turn gzipped file into one tar.gz archive in-place?

Tags: tar, gzip

I have a lot (~5 millions) of small files, each one compressed individually with `gzip`. I would like to turn them into one big `tar.gz` archive to save some space (metadata), but there are limitations:

- I don't have enough space to decompress files and compress again into `tar.gz`, so I have to do it *in place*. Reduction ratio is quite nice, about 15:1.
- I can't use much CPU time, so recompression may take a very long time.
- Files can't be moved to somewhere else or removed, because *important security reasons*

So. What can I do?

Comment: Buy an additional hard drive.

Comment: So just to be clear: You don't have space for uncompressing the files and you also don't have space for an archive of the compressed files?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compress the archive, just add the already compressed files to it.

```
tar -cf archive.tar directory_with_compressed_files
```

Comment: I can't do that, because I have no space for new archive :) And my `tar` version don't have `--remove-files` option.

Comment: @maln0ir Ah, I thought you said you did not have space for the decompressed files.

Answer (score 0):

If only have enough space to do a small number of files, you can do the archiving in chunks, and it can even be automated if you want. Assuming your files are stored something like this:

```
.
+-dir0000
| +-file0000.gz
| +-file0001.gz
| [...]
+-dir0001
| +-file1000.gz
| +-file1001.gz
[...]
```

For each directory, run (from the shared root of the files):

```
tar rf /path/to/archive_name.tar dir_name
rm -r dir_name
```

If you're OK with automating this (I tried it and it worked, but you get error messages from `find` which can be ignored) try the following:

```
find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c "tar rf /path/to/archive_name '{}' && rm -r '{}'" \;
```

(As usual, try this on a test directory structure first so you can verify it's doing what you want!)

I quoted the `{}` in case your directories have spaces. If you have a flat file structure, then you can do something similar, only without `-type d`. Make sure not to use `+` at the end of `-exec`, or else `find` will try to do a whole bunch of files/directories at a time, which defeats the point of breaking the archiving into pieces in the first place!

Eventually all the files will be moved into the archive. It'll be slow, but it can be done.